# LINQ Compare two arrays and return the position and values that do not match

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

In grading student exams there are  two arrays of characters which represent correct questions answers / student answers. The goal is grade and  identify the missed questions and to  display the question number and  correct answer answer and student choice.

The code below loops through two arrays and identifies the missed questions. I would like to use LINQ to refactor the existing code. I have looked at the .except, .union and .intersect operators but don't feel they are the right fit for the  task at hand.  What standard query operators are reasonable to use to calculate the correct results and what would this code look like?

```
void Main()
{
    char[] correctAnswer ="ACBCDABCABDDCCBA".ToCharArray();
    char[] studentsChoice = "ABBCDDBCAADDACCA".ToCharArray();

    for( int x = 0; x<=correctAnswer.Count()-1;x++)
    {
        if( ! correctAnswer[x].Equals(studentsChoice[x]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Question:{0} correctAnswer:{1}  StudentsChoice:{2}",x,  correctAnswer[x],studentsChoice[x]));
        }
}
```

**Output**

```
    Question:1 AnswerKey:C Correct:B
    Question:5 AnswerKey:A Correct:D
    Question:9 AnswerKey:B Correct:A
    Question:12 AnswerKey:C Correct:A
    Question:14 AnswerKey:B Correct:C
```

Comment: In this case, I can't think of a way linq can do any better than this approach since you have parallel arrays.

Comment: Are the two `char[]` in the same size always? (meaning a student for sure answered all questions). also if you want linq then show some linq attempt please.

Comment: Are you just wanting a more elegant solution? You can't really make this anymore efficient.

Comment: yes, I have a check around them if( studentsChoice.Length == correctAnswer.Length)

Comment: by the way linq code will work with string too `string correctAnswer ="ACBCDABCABDDCCBA";` and you don't need char array `char[] correctAnswer ="ACBCDABCABDDCCBA".ToCharArray();`

Comment: Leaving it as a string and not splitting into a char array is a great suggestion and very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add indexing to your answer keys and then simply compare it

```
    string[] result = studentsChoice.Select((c,i)=> new { index = i, choice = c })
    .Where(c=> c.choice != correctAnswer[c.index])
    .Select(c => $"Question:{c.index+1} AnswerKey:{c.choice} Correct:{correctAnswer[c.index]}")
.ToArray();
```

String formatting with older C# versions:

```
    string[] result = studentsChoice.Select((c,i)=> new { index = i, choice = c })
    .Where(c=> c.choice != correctAnswer[c.index])
    .Select(c => string.Format("Question:{0} AnswerKey:{1} Correct:{2}",c.index+1,c.choice,correctAnswer[c.index]))
.ToArray();
```

please check the working [**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TbOLiP)

Comment: Having to use select to grab the index makes this seem, meh, but in any case this answers the OP's question using linq. You still have to loop through the result to print it :/

Comment: What does the $ do in the select?  .Select(c => $

Comment: @Tinypond Well, its the same as `String.Format()` its introduced in C# 6, the same functionality but easier. `$"a={x}"` is same as `string.Format("a={0},x);`

Comment: @Tinypond You may use `string.Format` if you are using an older version.

Comment: I edited my answer and added `string.Format` version too. please check it.

Comment: @Tinypond I also added a demo to my answer please check it.