# C# Testing Framework Loop Through Test Cases

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, testing

I am looking to use MS testing framework to test a tax calculator and needs to run over 100 test cases. As see below, I have set up an array of testCases and loop through each but the when I run Tests, it only returns one return.

Question:

1. Is there a way for every test display result?
2. How do I return each test results? Currently, the system only returns values if failed.

```
            [DataTestMethod]
            public void CalculateResult(int val)
            {

                // arrange
                int[] testCase = { 1000,2000, 35000, 400003, 59509 };

                foreach (int income in testCase)
                {

                    double expectOutput = TaxCalculator(income);

                    // act
                    
                    SUT.GeneralTaxRule generalTaxationRule = new SUT.GeneralTaxRule(income);
                    
                    double actualOutput = generalTaxationRule.getTax();

                    // assert
                    Assert.AreEqual(expectOutput, actualOutput);
                    Console.WriteLine(expectOutput, actualOutput);
                }

            }
```

Comment: Does `TaxCalculator()` have the same code as `getTax()`?

Comment: @crowcoder, yes.

Comment: Then all you are testing is that both methods return the same thing.  That is not a valid test.

Comment: If you take no account of Testing Framework, you may need: [Easiest way to compare arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232758/12666543) or [LINQ Compare two arrays and return the position and values that do not match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48473551/12666543)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `DataTestMethod` attribute you should have attributes for each `DataRow`

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(1000)]
[DataRow(2000)]
// etc
public void CalculateResult(int income)
{
    double expectOutput = TaxCalculator(income);

    // act                        
    SUT.GeneralTaxRule generalTaxationRule = new SUT.GeneralTaxRule(income);                        
    double actualOutput = generalTaxationRule.getTax();

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectOutput, actualOutput);
    Console.WriteLine(expectOutput, actualOutput);
}
```

Another way you might achieve the same is using `DynamicData` attribute

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(TestData), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void CalculateResult(int income)
{
    double expectOutput = TaxCalculator(income);

    // act                        
    SUT.GeneralTaxRule generalTaxationRule = new SUT.GeneralTaxRule(income);                        
    double actualOutput = generalTaxationRule.getTax();

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectOutput, actualOutput);
    Console.WriteLine(expectOutput, actualOutput);
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData()
{
    yield return new object[] { 1000 };
    yield return new object[] { 2000 };
    /// etc.
}
```

You could data drive the data however you like in `TestData` above (eg a file, a database, or hardcoded). There is other options for `DynamicDataSourceType` as well which you could investigate.

Comment: yes but the problem is I will have an array of 100 different value, very troublesome to do this in MS framework? Any better way?

Answer (score 1):

Using Xunit, you could do it like this:

```
private static int[] incomesArray = { 1000,2000, 35000, 400003, 59509 };

public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetIncomeTestData =>
                incomesArray
                .Select(x => new object[] { x })
                .ToArray();

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(GetIncomeTestData))]
public void CalculateResult(int income)
{
    // arrange
    var expectOutput = TaxCalculator(income);
    var generalTaxationRule = new SUT.GeneralTaxRule(income);
                
    // act            
    var actualOutput = generalTaxationRule.getTax();

    // assert
    Assert.Equal(expectOutput, actualOutput);
}
```

You can have as many values in `incomesArray` as you'd like and you'll be able to see the result for each test value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `[DataTestMethod]` you can add test cases through one or more `[DataRow(...)]` attribute(s):

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(1000)]
[DataRow(2000)]
[DataRow(35000)]
[DataRow(400003)]
[DataRow(59509)]
public void CalculateResult(int val)
{
    double expectOutput = TaxCalculator(val);

    // act  
    SUT.GeneralTaxRule generalTaxationRule = new SUT.GeneralTaxRule(val);
    double actualOutput = generalTaxationRule.getTax();

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectOutput, actualOutput);
    Console.WriteLine(expectOutput, actualOutput);
}
```

That way you can inspect the test result for each `val` in the Test Explorer window.